# how to Roll multiple rows into a single row and column inspecific order in for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, subquery

I have Two Tables pay_tbl and bill_tbl in my Sql Server Database, Their columns are

---

`pay_tbl{pay_id typy int --pk, pay_name type varchar} bill_tbl{pay_id type int --> Fk,bill_date type datetime,bill_amount type int,bill-status type varchar}`

---

i am trying to get billing history of last 5 month of each pay_ID with month name, i tried a query which is working fine and returning me history of each month row by row but i dun want this, its returning me result in this way

---

```
pay_ID          Month            Amount To Pay    Bill Status
----------      -------------    --------------  -----------
1               January           5000           paid
1               December          6000           Not Paid
2               January           3000           paid
2               December          800            Not Paid
```

but i want result in this way

```
pay_ID Month  Amount To Pay Bill Status   Month  Amount To Pay    Bill Status

1  January      5000           paid      December 6000            Not Paid
2  January      3000           Paid  December 800            Not paid
```

how i can achieve this ? this query i tried which returned me above result

```
SELECT    DATENAME(month, b.bill_date) AS 'Month',b.bill_amount as 'Amount   To Pay', b.bill_status AS 'Bill Status'
 FROM  bill_tbl b
INNER JOIN
          pay_tbl AS p ON b.payment_id = p.pay_ID
```

Comment: what happened to November and more why you need result like this

Comment: Better is , do this your presentation  layer. If you really need this in SQL query then check the keyword PIVOT...

Comment: i just skipped November as an example and i need this to show in gridview, means each row have one pay id

Comment: In out put you are showing for January 5000 and 2000 but in the sample data 5000 and 3000.

Comment: @mohan111 do u have solution for this ? i just entered dummy example and forget to have same value but am sure you understand what i want

Comment: please go through SO instructions carefully before posting question . we are here to help you but you should ask in correct way

Comment: @mohan111 you dun have solution so take a side am not here tagging to give me solution, Thanks

Comment: Yeah I have the solution but I'm asking you to be more clear when asking question @mjunaid

Comment: @mohan111 which thing is making you confuse ? every thing is clear you may read again

Answer (score 1):

Sample data :

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
        (pay_ID int, Month varchar(8), AmountToPay int, BillStatus varchar(8))
    ;

    INSERT INTO @Table1
        (pay_ID, Month, AmountToPay, BillStatus)
    VALUES
        (1, 'January', 5000, 'paid'),
        (1, 'December', 6000, 'Not Paid'),
        (2, 'January', 3000, 'paid'),
        (2, 'December', 800, 'Not Paid')
    ;
```

**Script**

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select *, row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY pay_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN from @Table1 )
,CTE1 AS (
Select * from  CTE where RN = 1 )
,CTE2 AS (
Select * from  CTE where RN = 2 )


Select row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY J_Month  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID,
J_Month,
J_AmountToPay,
J_BillStatus,
D_Month,
D_AmountToPay,
D_BillStatus 
    from (
    select  
            C.pay_ID J_pay_ID,
            C.Month J_Month,
            C.AmountToPay J_AmountToPay,
            C.BillStatus J_BillStatus,
            CC.Month D_Month,
            CC.AmountToPay D_AmountToPay,
            CC.BillStatus D_BillStatus,
            row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY CC.pay_ID  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RNN 
from CTE1 C,CTE2 CC
)T WHERE T.RNN  = 1
```

Comment: its just for two months January and December ?

Comment: That's what you asked for.  Can you see now why @Mohan111 asked for more details?

Comment: @destination-data more detail ? like ?? can you explain please  ? should i share my whole project with you then you will know all details ?

Comment: @destination-data we have answered his question based on his data provided . More over he is not willing to follow the SO Pattern . anyway he is a newbie .cheers

Comment: There are lots of questions on SO.  They are all competing for attention.  As a consequence, the easier questions are more likely to receive an answer.  If you want help, it is your job to make your question as easy to answer as possible.  This takes time and effort.  Read up on MCVEs.  Take a trip through the help pages.  (@Mohan111 - I love this answer.  Nice work!).

Comment: @mohan111 yes no doubt and dun forget every professional once a newbie,

Comment: @destination-data no doubt clear questions answers quickly but here is the problem easy questions gets answer quickly than complex one, well if next time i will try to ask easiest question here then you and other professional ill never harass, new users Thanks For Your Time